# Counterexample to: If $f$ is a continuous function, then in any closed interval on which $f$ is defined, there are a finite number of isolated zeros

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I was working on an exercise where my argument could be made much easier **if** the following statement was true:

> If $f$ is a continuous function, then in any closed interval on which $f$ is defined, there are a finite number of isolated zeros.

I began to **suspect that the statement was untrue** and tried to think of counterexamples. I think that I may have found the appropriate one (I just want to make sure that the function I defined is legitimate):

---

Consider the following continuous function $f$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\, x=\frac{1}{n} \text{ for any }n \geq 1\\
 -\left|x-\frac{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}}{2} \right|+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)}{2}&\text{ for any } x \text{ satisfying } \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n-1} \text{ for any }n \geq 1 \\ 
0 &\text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}
$$

This graph looks something like:

[image: Graph]

...minus the portions that dip below the $x$-axis. I believe that this function is continuous throughout the interval $[0,1]$, in particular, at $x=0$ due to the converging-towards-zero nature of the absolute value peaks.

---

Now, let $s_n$ represent any arbitrary $0$ of $f$...i.e. $s_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \geq 1$.

For this $s_n$, consider the following $\delta_n$:
$$\delta_n = \frac{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}}{2}$$

Then one can demonstrate that for any $x$ in the punctured neighborhood $(s_n-\delta_n,s_n+\delta_n)\setminus\{s_n\}$, $f(x)\neq 0$.

Firstly, we can show that $\frac{1}{n+1} \lt \frac{1}{n}-\frac{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}}{2} \iff s_{n+1} \lt s_n - \delta_n $.

Secondly, we can show that $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}}{2} \lt \frac{1}{n} \iff s_{n+1}+\delta_{n+1} \lt s_n$.

As such, $s_n$ must be an isolated zero.

Further, because $\mathbb N$ is an unbounded set, there are an infinite number of $\frac{1}{n}$ that have the property $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$...each of which has a corresponding $\delta_n$ where the punctured neighborhood is non-zero. Therefore, there are an infinite number of isolated zeros $s_n$ of the continuous function $f$ along the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: I didn't read the details carefully. Wouldn't $x\sin\frac1x$ be an example? (Say on $[0,1]$ or on $[-1,1]$.) One could also make it differentiable at $0$, like $x^2\sin\frac1x$

Comment: @Mirko significantly simpler than mine! Cheers~

Comment: (+1) for execution of technical details. However, as a bit of advice, when trying to determine for yourself (thus, not constrained to prove by whatever "course/book/instructor legalities" that might be present), you don't need to spend an hour or whatever trying to obtain explicit formulas. It is enough to sketch out some possible graphs by hand. In this case the only real insight needed is that you can make the wiggles above-to-below-to-above the $x$-axis occur infinitely often "at some point", and you can obtain continuity at the point by making the vertical deviations approach zero.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for the commentary. Is it legitimate to assume that "if I can draw a curve that passes the vertical line test" then there is some corresponding/matching "function whose assignment rules can be explicitly written out"?  My concern would be that I can draw something that satisfies the conditions of whatever it is I am trying to prove...but that my drawing cannot be instantiated with the tools of math.

Comment: The problem is with "assignment rules can be explicitly written out" -- what are allowable explicit operations/formulas? (polynomials, step functions, trig, exponential, inverses, expressible as a convergent infinite series of such functions, elliptic functions, hypergeometric functions, etc.) But if we're not asking whether the function can be expressed in a certain way, but simply whether it exists, then any set of points (regardless of how weird) in the plane satisfying the vertical line test is the graph of a function.

Comment: In case you're interested, for an example where I defined a function by simply constructing a weird subset of the plane that satisfies the vertical line test, see *2. A FUNCTION WHOSE GRAPH IS DENSE IN THE PLANE* in [this 5 October 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/pI8-E8YALwU/m/vdSLIgK70JgJ).